# 4k playback - GPU in PCI-E 3.0 x8 slot

Tags: graphics-card

I am building server/workstation computer that will be main computer for home use with virtual machine operating systems for family users. In addition to this
I would like to use it also as 2 separate Kodi players (tv in  living room and bedroom). Can cheapest cards that support 4k playback (f.ex. GeForce GT 1030 or GTX 650) will be able to playback movies if they will be connected to PCI-E 3.0 x8 slot (mainboard that I would like to buy doesnt have more x16 slots)?

Comment: If it is a x16 physical slot, but with only 8 lanes connected then it will probably work fine.

Comment: For video, I suspect part of the bottleneck is in the actual outputs and the system's ability to process the video

Comment: I would like to buy one of cheapest supermicro series dual lga 2011v3 xeon mainboards that have pci-e 3.0 x8 slots. Video cards will be probably low profile Gigabyte GeForce GT 1030 with passive coolers. I just want to be sure that they will fit and going to be able playback 4k videos for kodi media centers